# ag-grid not loading at all in IE11 with Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

My ag-grid works fine in all other browsers, but when I open it with IE it does not load at all. No error messages show in the console. Note that the rest of the Angular app loads just fine, just not the `ag-grid-angular` component`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

polyfill.ts

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10, IE11, and Chrome <55 requires all of the following polyfills.
 *  This also includes Android Emulators with older versions of Chrome and Google Search/Googlebot
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

my component template (for brevity, please assume that I am passing a valid `gridOptions` object filled with data)

```
<div class="container">
  <ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-material" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Comment: 20.0.0 has problem with IE, try 20.1.0-beta or earlier ag-grid version

Comment: Tried 20.1.0-beta, 19.x, and 18.x....all the same thing. Thank you though.

Comment: After I upgraded from 18.1 to 20.0 the only way to display something in IE was to set domLayout=normal and explicitly set grid height. However it was working fine before (I was using auto-height). Also installation of 20.1 beta I could use autoHeight again. Possibly you've hit another bug in this area.

Comment: For me this fixed:
used 20.1.0-beta.0 version. And used the property domLayout="autoHeight"

Comment: Bless both of your souls!!!! 20.1.0-beta.0 + `domLayout="autoHeight"` was the solution! The autoHeight was required for the grid to render, and upgrading the version is what makes the row data actually load. Praise! :D Feel free to create an answer and I will accept it :)